# .net TransactionScope Exception

Tags: c#, .net, transactions

My Code something like this

```
try
{
    using (TransactionScope iScope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        try
        {
            isInsertSuccess = InsertProfile(account);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }

        if (isInsertSuccess)
        {
            iScope.Complete();
            retValue = true;
        }
    }
}
catch (TransactionAbortedException tax)
{
    throw;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw;
}
```

Now what happen is that even if my value is TRUE a TransactionAbortedException Exception occurs randomly, but data get's inserted/updated in DB.

Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: Why are you declaring three variables named `rethrow` and not doing anything with them?  Also, why do you have two identical `catch` blocks for different types of exceptions?

Comment: If you are getting intermittent errors, the problem may not be with this isoloated piece of code, but could be caused by the integrations with other code, such as database deadlocks. What does the error message say?

Comment: @ SLaks isInsertSuccess value is TRUE

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As  the [`TransactionAbortedException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionabortedexception.aspx) documentation says,

> This exception is also thrown when an attempt is made
>   to commit the transaction and the
>   transaction aborts.

This is why you see the exception even after calling [`Transaction.Complete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.complete.aspx): the `Complete` method is not the same thing as `Commit`:

> calling this method [`TransactionScope.Complete`] does not guarantee
>   a commit of the transaction. It is
>   merely a way of informing the
>   transaction manager of your status

The transaction isn't committed until you exit the using statement: see the [`CommittableTransaction.Commit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.committabletransaction.commit.aspx) documentation for details. At that point any actions participating in the transaction may vote to abort the transaction and you'll get a `TransactionAbortedException`.

To debug the underlying problem you need to analyze the exception details and stack trace. As Mark noted in a comment, it may well be caused by a deadlock or another interaction with other database processes.

Comment: +1 Good explanation, particularly pointing out that Complete is just a vote.